# Group each couple of row's table as unique element

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
<table>
        <tr class="initial" onmouseover="this.className='highlight'" onmouseout="this.className='initial'">
            <td rowspan="2">ELEMENT 1</td>
            <td class="value">val 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="initial" onmouseover="this.className='highlight'" onmouseout="this.className='initial'">
            <td>val2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="initial" onmouseover="this.className='highlight'" onmouseout="this.className='initial'">
            <td rowspan="2">ELEMENT 2</td>
            <td>val a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="initial" onmouseover="this.className='highlight'" onmouseout="this.className='initial'">
            <td>val b</td>
        </tr>         
    </table>​
```

Each couple of `tr` should be colored when mouse is over. This is not possible (e.g. if mouse is over ELEMENT 2 cell, then "Element 2" and "Value a" cells are colored, while "Value b" is not.). How can I group element together? What I want is: if I'm with mouse upon Element 1, Value 1 or Value 2 cell both (three) cells need to be colored. What can I do? Here is an example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/PA4y6/

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: can you use jQuery or some other libraries?

Comment: You should try to avoid using `on*="h()"` or `elem.on* = h(){};` You could put the event listener on the `tr` elements, and in your function check the `e` which is the first argument and use it's `e.target` or `e.srcElement` to learn about the event itself, which is using a parent (`tr`? `table`?)j element to [*delegate* it's event to another, lower element](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent). jQuery is all over delegates, for instance.

Comment: Why should I prefear delegate approach rather than direct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way would be to wrap the rows you want to be grouped in a `<tbody>` and bind the listener to that.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PA4y6/1/)

Comment: which strict? multiple `tbody` is fine in [xhtml strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) `(tbody+|tr+)`